# Create multiple xlsx files with charts Python

Tags: python, csv, charts, xlsx

I'm looking for a massive python code to create xlsx files from my csv data. I need a file for a `Cliente` and there I need all information about the `Cliente`as I show you down. The point is I need to separate the csv data in `Cliente` and run my code for each `Cliente`

```
                    Cliente       Fecha      Subastas  Importe_a_pagar_a_medio
0                    ID         01/12/2017    1000                     1.78
1                    ID         02/12/2017    1200                     1.20
```

In the other file:

```
                    Cliente       Fecha      Subastas  Importe_a_pagar_a_medio
2                    Ad         01/12/2017     600                     4.46
3                    Ad         02/12/2017     800                     4.66
4                    Ad         03/12/2017    1000                     4.86
```

I have my code for a simple xlsx to draw my charts:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('ac.csv')
subastadas = list(df['Subastadas'])
revenue = list(df['Revenue'])
fecha = list(df['Fecha'])

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = subastadas

worksheet.write_column('A1', fecha)
worksheet.write_column('B1', data)
worksheet.write_column('C1', revenue)
# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3', 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3', 'line':{'color': 'red'}})
chart2.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3', 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3', 'line':{'color': 'blue'}})
# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('F1', chart)
worksheet.insert_chart('F15', chart2)
workbook.close()
```

csv data:

```
                    Cliente       Fecha      Subastas  Importe_a_pagar_a_medio
0                    ID         01/12/2017    1000                     1.78
1                    ID         02/12/2017    1200                     1.20
2                    Ad         01/12/2017     600                     4.46
3                    Ad         02/12/2017     800                     4.66
4                    Ad         03/12/2017    1000                     4.86
```